# Find the origin of MCG0007 compiler warning

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-native

I'm trying to compile an uwp app but I get the following error:

> Warning       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'ntdll!RtlGetVersion' for method 'System.Int32 Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.Native.NativeMethods.Windows.RtlGetVersion(Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.Native.NativeMethods.Windows.RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEX)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.

The thing is that I can't find the origin, is there a way to debug this issue? Or how could I find the library that is causing the issue?

UPDATE: I attach a sample project that throws the same compilation error. If anyone could take a look. I'll be very grateful.

[Sample project](https://agrovidaec-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/sistemas_agrovida_ec/Ec61Olw4KuFOgZS0o7M4iY0BiWX3l_RK02pDZ_RmbOlGHg?e=tjKfsv)

UPDATE 2: I have an UWP app that uses the following nuget packages:

This app uses 3 .netstandard libraries.

The UWP app contains the following references.

```
<PackageReference Include="AdaptiveCards">
      <Version>1.2.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter">
      <Version>2.6.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics">
      <Version>2.6.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes">
      <Version>2.6.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob">
      <Version>11.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.9</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement">
      <Version>10.1901.28001</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml">
      <Version>2.3.191211002</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed">
      <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MimeKit">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MvvmLight">
      <Version>5.4.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green">
      <Version>2.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core">
      <Version>2.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Win2D.uwp">
      <Version>1.24.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

It uses 3 .netStandard libraries.

ServicesLibrary

```
<PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="7.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter" Version="2.6.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="2.6.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Portable.BouncyCastle" Version="1.8.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.7.0" />
```

DataLibrary

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore" Version="3.0.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore" Version="3.0.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.Expressions.Eval" Version="3.0.11" />
```

SigningLibrary

```
 <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle.NetCore" Version="1.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.AccessControl" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Xml" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Permissions" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Principal.Windows" Version="4.7.0" />
```

The UWP references the ServicesLibrary and the DataLibrary, the ServicesLibrary references the SigningLibrary and the DataLibrary. That's the anatomy of the app that I'm trying to compile in release mode.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: *Or how could I find the library that is causing the issue?* well, with google? it seems like some microsoft azure library

Comment: @Rup that's a good idea. I will do that. I'm trying to compile for windows 10 using sdk 1809 - 1903

Comment: Actually ["RtlGetVersion is the kernel-mode equivalent of the user-mode GetVersionEx"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlgetversion) - are you using any code that's possibly intended for kernel mode? I'm not sure how you'd get that in UWP though.

Comment: @Selvin I have an uwp, and 3 different libraries. So the thing is I don't know which one or where is the error being thrown.

Comment: Hi @Michael , If it does not contain sensitive data, please share your code. We ca n’t locate the cause of the problem based on the error message alone. Did you introduce a library that doesn't work with UWP? (For example, only the `.NET Framework` is supported in the dependencies, not the `.NET Standard`), or some special features not supported by UWP are used (UWP has strict permission management)

Comment: You can use `ILDASM` (part of the SDK) to dump each of your three libraries, looking for `RtlGetVersion`.

Comment: @Michael Please [edit] your question to include your [mcve] here on Stack Overflow, not as an external link.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFTI've attached a sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Progman I'll try to update the post as well. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Michael Hi, for UWP apps, try using `Class Library (Universal Windows)` instead of `Class Library (.Net Standard)`,

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT , but isn't  .NetStandard the way to go in order to create a cross platform library? Or the best way to go is create a library for UWP using Class Library (Universal Windows) and another library for a Xamarin app for instance? Thanks

Comment: @Michael `.Net Standard` is a specification that provides a common way to build code that can serve as the basis for cross-platform code sharing. But UWP has its own special characteristics. For example, you can access the file through the path in `.Net Standard`, but you cannot do so in UWP. (You can get the `File` object in `.Net Standard`, but `StorageFile` is recommended in UWP. ), There are many similar situations. So it is recommended to use `Class Library (Universal Windows)` in UWP projects.

Comment: Thank you @RichardZhang-MSFT, I'm going to use Class Library (Universal Windows) and see if it solves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

After all the suggestions, and trying to reproduce the compiler error. I find out that the Z.EntityFramework library was the one causing the issue. Looking at the logs all that I found was a reference to EntityFrameworkCore, related to the compiler error. But from that I started to remove libraries until I finally found the one that was causing the issue.

It's very hard and a bit frustrating finding the solution with such a cryptic message as `MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `It's very hard and a bit frustrating finding the solution` sums up our UWP experience quite nicely :) :/